# Wordpress - How to get all parents ID of a child

Tags: wordpress

Can anybody help me? I want to get all the parents ID of a child page in wordpress

> Parrent 1
>
> --Parent 1.1
>
> ----Parent 1.1.1
>
> ------Child Page

So I want to get the the ID of Parent 1, Parent 1.1, Parent 1.1.1

Thanks,
Made

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$pages = get_pages('child_of=X');
foreach($pages as $child) {
echo $child->ID; // The child ID
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

check this post hope it will help you.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/query-child-pages-of-a-current-page-and-loop-through-each-child-page

Answer (score 0):

with in the global $post you can simply do is

use

```
$post->post_parent
```

for Parent 1.1.1 that's for first parent

and you can look in

```
$post->ancestors
```

array for other parents

Answer (score 0):

You need `get_post_ancestors()`;

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors